# How can I render alert method from node.js to jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, interpolation

I want to render 'jade view' with data.

like below,

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('alert', {msg: 'hi!'});
});
```

So, I wrote the jade code below: (alert.jade)

```
script.
    alert(#{msg});
```

2)

```
script.
    alert(=msg);
```

3)

```
script.
    alert(msg);
```

But nothing works.

How can I render it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your script. tag

```
script.
    var msgStr = !{JSON.stringify(msg)};
    alert(msgStr)
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it does solve your problem and feel great to help you. :-)

Comment: It was my first Questions in stackoverflow.com. So I did'nt know how accept an answer. sorry :)